# PDO Misunderstanding

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am writing my PHP blog engine. I am using PDO for it. And now, when I am writing class Member - I have an error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in
>   /home/tucnak/Server/scripts/php/classes/Member.php on line 42

And source code of my Class:

```
public function authMember($user, $password)
{
    $password = hashIt($password);
    $count = 100500;
    $count = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM users-general WHERE nick = $user AND password = $password;")->fetch();
    echo($count);
    // if ($count == 1){ return 1; } else { throw new Exception("",491); }
}
```

I have an error using this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query probably fails because you don't have quotes wrapped around your query.

When that happens, `query()` will return `false` instead of an object, breaking the chain.

Don't do it this way; run the query first, save its result, then check whether it's false.

By the way, you should really use prepared statements - your current statement is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: `nick = $user AND password = $password;` is missing quotes around `$user` and `$password`

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT count(*) FROM `users-general` WHERE nick = '$user' AND password = '$password'"
```

note the single quotes of 2 **different** types

Thought, your misunderstanding has nothing to do with PDO. it's basic SQL syntax you have to learn